# A non-main activity doesn't start with Share intent

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to write an app with Xamarin Forms whose purpose is to be a share target so you can trim down URIs according to patterns stored in a SQLite database.

Configuration menus are all part of the main activity but I would like to have a separate one that does not render, but only connects to the database to fetch the filters and apply them. However, the activity does not seem to start the app -- e.g. if I kill it in the process manager, sharing to the app simply does not do anything (it works when the app is still active). There seems to be something about the activity/app lifecycle that I am missing, as I have never written an Android app before.

This is my additional activity:

```cs
[Activity(Label = "RemoveParamsActivity", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay")]
[IntentFilter(new []{Intent.ActionSend}, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "text/*", Label = "Strip")]
public class RemoveParamsActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        if (!(Intent is { Action: Intent.ActionSend })) return;
        var filtersService = new SQLiteFiltersService();
        var text = Intent.Extras?.GetString(Intent.ExtraText);
        if (text == null) return;
        var filters = filtersService.GetEnabledFilters();
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            if (!filter.TryMatch(text, out var filteredResult)) continue;
            Clipboard.SetTextAsync(filteredResult).Wait();
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Filtered URL copied to clipboard.", ToastLength.Long)?.Show();
            Finish();
            return;
        }
        Clipboard.SetTextAsync(text).Wait();
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "No applicable filter found. Copied content as-is.", ToastLength.Long)?.Show();
        Finish();
    }
}
```

It uses the `NoDisplay` theme so it does not switch away or anything but instead processes the shared content in the background. As far as I can tell, this *should* be enough to do everything, but that doesn't happen. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `OnCreate` method triggered or not ?

Comment: It is. Or at least, it is when the app is running. I haven't found a way of testing whether it is triggered when the app has been killed.